# my server side PHP still got hacked after reCaptcha (hundreds-spam-emails)

Tags: php, recaptcha, server-side

My previous question on StackOverflow was about that someone was sending me hundreds of spam emails every few hours. Now, I fixed the script on the server side but the next morning I still got 30 emails or something and my hosting company gave me a new password to my FTP and moved my index files to a backup map(website offline), they said it was hacked because of the suspicious script below. They said "This often happens via a leaked script in your website, a script that is "out of date". What does that mean? They say in the email that there is something with this script file. Which is impossible to hack in right because I used reCaptcha on the server side, is there something missing?

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
      $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];


      }


/* OUTCOMMENTED CODE BELOW DOESN'T LET FORM SEND IF EVERYTHING IS CHECKED???? 


    if(!$captcha){
          echo '<h2>Check captcha .</h2>';
          exit;
        }*/



    $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=(SECRETKEY)&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
            if($response.success==false)
            {
                echo '<span id="status" style="font-size:1vmax;color:red;">ReCaptcha ERROR</span>';
            }else
            {

        if( isset($_POST['n']) && isset($_POST['e']) && isset($_POST['mn']) && 

isset($_POST['m']) ){
        $n = $_POST['n']; // HINT: use preg_replace() to filter the data
        $e = $_POST['e'];
        $mn = $_POST['mn'];
        $m = nl2br($_POST['m']);
        $to = "gesternl@gester.nl"; 
        $from = $e;
        $subject = 'Contact Formulier-eng';
        $message = '<b>Naam:</b> '.$n.' <br><b>Email:</b> '.$e.' <br><b>Mobiel-nummer:</b> '.$mn.' <p>'.$m.'</p>';
        $headers = "Van: $from\n";
        $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        if( mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ){
            echo "success";
        } else {
            echo "The server failed to send a message. Please try again later. Thank you!";
        }
    }
        }
    ?>
```

I just uploaded it again to see what is going to happen now. Can someone please help me make this file secure for a hacker. Nobody really helped in the previous question but only gave advice without code (and I am nooby).

(The outcommented code around line 8 doesn't work which i don't understand, does someone know why is that why someone can hack into it maybe?)

And yes the code in the HTML for recaptcha is well linked with the public key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You've to sanitizing user input as said @kevin Cai
2. You've an error in line: `if($response.success==false)`

   ```
   $response=file_get_contents("......");

   $result = json_decode($response);

   if($result->success==false){
   ```

Comment: Excuse me @barmar for my format error, but my suggestion is correct, I don't want make polemic but the user Poemko probably need this information

Comment: I never said your solution is wrong. I just made it more readable.

Comment: Ok thanks, I've seen -1 and I don't understand why ... I'm quiet new here, sorry for my mistake

Comment: So   `$response=file_get_contents("");
    if($response.success==false)
    {`

Needs to be

`$response=file_get_contents("")
    $result = json_decode($response);
 if($result->success==false)
 {`

?

Comment: and was my private key exposed by doing it the wrong way(old-code)?

Comment: Your code is not working. I will read the reCapthca documentation again....

Comment: And i thought succes was something but it is nothing? what is succes? because that's whats holding the form to send. If i change the false to true it should echo something but it does nothing. `if($response.success==true)
    {
       echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('TRUE');</script>";` NOTHING HAPPENS?

Comment: @Poemko $response.success is an **ERROR**, big **ERROR** and you cannot validate the captcha response! The right method in your script is as I've explained!
The . (dot) in PHP is a concatenation operator

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Oke but why does the mail code only work if i put recaptcha false? if i put the mail code in the true statement with `if($result->success)` or `if(!$result) {}` it doesn't work as true but only works als false as the SUCCES code. That is what i don't understand. It is like it doesn't want to work as a true statement, it only works when the statement is wrong?

Comment: 1) You cannot verify with **if(!$result)** the google recaptha **2)** with the $response=file_get_contents("..."); you'll receive an answer that you can not check with a simple IF true or false **3)** that answer ($response) have to DE-CODIFY with json_decode so: with $result = json_decode($response); **4)** so in $result there will be specify if ["success"] is TRUE or FALSE **5)** and if($result->success==false) check if inside $result the ["success"] is FALSE **6)** $result->success return a boolean value FALSE or TRUE

Comment: I sended you messages on chat, i don't know if you are getting it so i am letting you know. Thank you

Comment: @Poemko Ok I've replied in chat

Answer (score 4):

```
$response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=(SECRETKEY)&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
if($response.success==false)
```

This fragment of code is an unfortunate bit of nonsense that has found its way into a lot of (terrible) tutorials. It provides no protection whatsoever -- the condition is always false, because `$response.success` is interpreted as concatenating the constant `success` to the API response returned by the reCaptcha API. This will cause the CAPTCHA to be always treated as valid, regardless of the user's input.

Use the Google reCaptcha library to verify responses from the reCaptcha API. It is available at: https://github.com/google/recaptcha

Comment: Yes i see that after a few hours now. But $response['succes']==false doesnt work and $response->succes==false doesnt work either. So i dont know what to do... I opened a new question with more code, can you please help me and guide me in this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51053286/what-is-wrong-with-my-form-php-recaptcha

Comment: And checking that library was the first thing i did but it didn't work either. That's why i am asking here

Answer (score 2):

You're not sanitizing user input, for one. You should fix that right away as it's a security flaw.

Comment: Your saying that as if i can know what you are saying without an explanation. And my hosting company said this "
Also do not forget to adjust your database connections to the new password." They are saying that WITHOUT even explaining how to do that. Do you know where i need to look to change the password in the database connection?

Comment: @poemko It sounds like you don't have the necessary experience and know-how to develop something like this for use in a production environment. Input sanitization and database credential configuration are web-app development 101 topics. It may be in your (and any of your clients that will have their data leaked) best interest to look at a solution that does not require custom development, or bringing in resources that can handle the security side for you.

Comment: I can just learn, everything is learn-able. But how does that database connection work its that just for wordpress because i have a database for it but i am not using it on this other database where i am talking about. My form doesn't send it to my email (yesterday it did) and it does send it to a inbox if i send a new email from another email account