# What is wrong with my form.php (reCaptcha)

Tags: javascript, php, recaptcha, server-side

i am now 12 hours on this problem because someone is spamming me with bots. I posted it before but without good results. I checked the code with alot of other examples. The problem starts when someone told me this was wrong ( `if($response.success==false)` ) and it should be  `if($result->success==false)` or `if($result['success']==false)` but the last two don't work, it doesn't send my form and hangs on 'please wait'. So what is wrong with this, is it something with my Mail code in the if statement, if so, what is it? I can't figure it out.

Thanks for your time. Help is appreciated and please be specific with a answer containing code not just links to another document guide.

```
  if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
          $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        }

         $response=json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=(SECRETKEY)&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']), true);
        if($response.success==false)
        {
            echo '<span id="status" style="font-size:1vmax;color:red;">ReCaptcha ERROR</span>';
        }else
        {

    if( isset($_POST['n']) && isset($_POST['e']) && isset($_POST['mn']) && isset($_POST['m']) ){
        $n = $_POST['n']; // HINT: use preg_replace() to filter the data
        $e = $_POST['e'];
        $mn = $_POST['mn'];
        $m = nl2br($_POST['m']);
        $to = "gesternl@gester.nl"; 
        $from = $e;
        $subject = 'Contact Formulier-eng';
        $message = '<b>Naam:</b> '.$n.' <br><b>Email:</b> '.$e.' <br><b>Mobiel-nummer:</b> '.$mn.' <p>'.$m.'</p>';
        $headers = "Van: $from\n";
        $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        if( mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ){
            echo "success";
        } else {
            echo "The server failed to send a message. Please try again later. Thank you!";
        }
    }
        }

    ?>
```

This is the javascript side:

```
function submitForm(){

           var recaptcha = $("#g-recaptcha-response").val();
   if (recaptcha === "") {
      event.preventDefault();
      //alert("Check ReCaptcha");

      document.getElementsByClassName("status-eng-error")[0].innerHTML = "<span style='font-size:15px;color:red;'>" + "Please check ReCaptcha" + "</span>"; 
   }
   else{

    "use strict";
    _("mybtn").disabled = true;
    _("status-eng").innerHTML = 'One moment please ...';
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append( "n", _("n").value );
    formdata.append( "e", _("e").value );
    formdata.append( "mn", _("mn").value );
    formdata.append( "m", _("m").value );
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open( "POST", "contactform-eng.php" );
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
            if(ajax.responseText == "success"){
                _("my_form").innerHTML = '<h2>Thankyou '+_("n").value+'. Your message has been sent successfully. We will respond to your message as soon as possible.<pre>Have a nice day!</pre></h2>';
            } else {
                _("status").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                _("mybtn").disabled = false;
            }
        }
    };
    ajax.send( formdata );
}
}
```

I am thinking that inside the javascript code it goes to ELSE and hang on   `_("status").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;` (Which is 'please wait' what i mentioned above)

Comment: I dont even understand where the succes stands for, what does succes do with a dot, after -> or inside [‘’]? I know that the last two don’t work. I have been searching for 5/6 hours and i still don’t know. That’s why i am asking here. So what should the code be to work AND send. I tried what you are saying but it doesn’t execute the mail code it just hangs on please wait. So your saying i can do this ‘$response.gettype()==false’ and what is gettype? Do i need to write something in that somewhere else?

Comment: Why do you think? What would you do if it was your own website. You have a answer on the code besides your comment? Because that’s what i need not that this question is a “ duplicate “ it is not a duplicate if the question is left unanswered and is not explained good enough for me